# How to show up message or warning modal , when button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
disabled={this.state.user_type.title === "" || this.checkDuplicateUserType()}
```

```js
checkDuplicateUserType = () => {
  let val = this.props.userTypes.includes(this.state.user_type.title.toLowerCase())
  if(val === true) {
    this.setState({warningModal:true})
    return val;
  }
  return  val;
}
```

Maximum update depth exceeded error shows up for above code.

Comment: I think we should store `val` in a state to avoid this problem; in this case the call to `checkDuplicateUserType` is done in a loop because of the component update

Comment: You need to show the modal when the state "warningModal" is true so in your jsx you should check that status and show your modal accordingly...

it should be something like:

if(this.state.warningModal){ return <Modal />}


but without any other code fragment I can not write all the component stuffs (I suppose you are using class component btw)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this with out calling function .

```
componentDidMount() {
    let val = this.props.userTypes.includes(this.state.user_type.title.toLowerCase())
    this.setState({ warningModal: val })
}
```

and your condition for disabled be like this

```
disabled = { this.state.user_type.title === "" || this.state.warningModal }
```

Comment: Thanks Arpit, but it didnt work, I assume it's because the warning modal should open when the user enters data and matches with the condition